# Prove that exists a linear continuous functional satisfying...

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $E$ be a normed space over the field of real numbers.

I have to prove that given two convex sets $A$, $B$ in $E$, with positive distance between then, there exists a linear continuous functional such that the infimum of its value on the set $A-B$ its equal to that distance, and it has norm 1.

I have a strong guess that this question can be solved using the geometric Hahn Banach (second form), taking the closure of $(A-B)$, wich is still convex and closed, and the set $\{0\}$. But this give me a inequality, and I dont know how to continue.

I need a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=\inf_{x\in A-B} ||x|| $ then $d$ is the distance between the sets $A,B.$ Consider the ball $K=K(0, d) =\{ x\in X : ||x||<r \}$ and the set $C=A-B $ since both the sets are convex, $K$ is open then there exist a linear functional of norm $1$ such that $f(k)<s\leq f(c) $ for all $k\in K$ and $c\in C.$ But for $c\in C $ we have $f(c)\geq 0 $ and $f(c) \leq ||c|| $ hence $\inf_{c\in C} f(c) \leq \inf_{c\in C} ||c|| = d$ thus $d\geq s$ but $\sup_{k\in K} f(k) =d\cdot \sup_{||x||\leq 1} f(x) =d $ thus $s\geq d.$  Therefore $s=d=\inf_{c\in C} f(c).$